# How to customize TextCell wihen the ItemSource is just a List<string>?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make a ListView of strings in Xamarin.Forms, but I didnt find how to do that in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance).

```
  <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell>
                     <!--How to customize this textcell with the content of the array?-->
                    </TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I tried this, but I only get the error that the key does not exist in the dictionary. How do I customize ListView-Cell when the ItemSource is just strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `.` syntax for binding the current object

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
```